# ASPxPopupControl Uncaught ReferenceError: TicketPopUp is not defined

Tags: c#, devexpress

After updated devExpress from 12.1 to 23.2

ASPxPopupControl not working

Here is the code

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="TicketPopUp" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="TicketPopUp" AllowDragging="true" HeaderText="Ticket Detail" PopupElementID="TicketID"
    CloseAction="CloseButton" Height="750px" Width="100%" Modal="True" PopupAction="None" AllowResize="true" ViewStateMode="Disabled" ContentStyle-Paddings-Padding="1px"
    PopupHorizontalAlign="LeftSides" PopupVerticalAlign="TopSides" ShowCloseButton="true" HeaderStyle-BackColor="AliceBlue" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
    <ContentCollection>
        <dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl2" runat="server">
        </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
    </ContentCollection>
    <ClientSideEvents Closing="CloseTicketPopUp" />
</dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

Here is js function to show it on the brwoser

```
      TicketPopUp.SetContentUrl("/Members/CustomerSupport/InterfaceCreateSupportTicket.aspx?TicketID=" + keyValue + "&mode=" + mode);
```

The thing is console.log(this.TicketPopUp) is undefiend means it is not written on the browserD

Comment: There is a high chance some of methods/properties are obsolete in new version and the upgrade program did not update them. May be rewriting the code solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue is this

After changing this from

`<ClientSideEvents Closing="CloseTicketPopUp" />`

To

`<ClientSideEvents CloseUp="function(s, e) { s.CloseTicketPopUp(); }"/>`

It is now working fine.